# Are azure durable functions a suitable alternative for azure service bus?

Tags: azure, function

In our current architecture we use a service bus in combination with an Azure Function bus. The service bus is there to make sure that the function app is not overloaded. Reading Microsoft's documentation suggests that durable function might be an alternative. I don't fully understand why i wouldn't need the service-bus anymore. Is it not possible to overload durable functions?

Comment: Durable Functions uses Azure Storage queues internally, which I think cannot perform at the same level of Service Bus queues. Of course it is possible to overload a Durable Function. If there are too many messages going around, their processing will slow down.

Comment: Can you please share the documentation link? 'Reading Microsoft's documentation suggests that durable function might be an alternative. '

Comment: *The service bus is there to make sure that the function app is not overloaded.* -> one of the characteristics of serverless functions is that is [scales very well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#scale).

Answer (score 0):

ServiceBus + (Azure Function Apps) are good example of Store And Process strategy. The messages are stored before they hit the processing. Here, the Function-App should be doing one unit of work, say reading from the database based on the message received. The data thus read should be pushed to another queue and let another function do the processing. That way a de-coupled architecture can be achieved. However, in general practice, we try to do many things in a Function-App, to save us from complexity. This is good sometimes, if the workload is small and if the response has to be real-time.

If the workload is heavy, like reading from multiple sources or combining the results from the various responses, then a normal function is going to time out. This is where Durable comes in. It takes as much time as it wants, to complete a workload. It can wait for other part of the program to complete. It can spin-up as many function in parallel to achieve parallel programming etc. I do not think it is a store and process mechanism. Its a programming construct to achieve asynchronous processing.

I would use Service-Bus + Durable, if each of the message in the Queue requires heavy lifting and that the client is not expecting any real time response.